# ADAL for Android - What is the correct way to handle errors?

Tags: android, error-handling, adal

When using ADAL for Android I found something a bit confusing regarding the acquireToken() API error handling.

From the source code it seems that error handling should be accomplished by catching **AuthenticationException** and inspecting its **ADALError** enum property.
However, the **AuthenticationResult** class has an **AuthenticationStatus** property and it could return as **Failed** in some cases (and then I suppose you should inspect the **errorCode** & **errorDescription** properties but these don't conform to **ADALError** enum).

Also, it seems that the (**AuthenticationResult.getStatus()==Failed**) case will return on the **onSuccess**() callback method since the **onError**() only returns exceptions.

Can someone clear this for me?
I would like to know what are all the possible error paths so I can handle all of them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are used to report on errors encountered within the ADAL client code. Error code helps to identify issues such as missing app permission for internet, connection issue, invalid redirectUri format. It also helps for common issues such as SSL handshake. The AuthenticationResult is where errors returned from the server, either AAD or ADFS, are reported.  The fact that the onSuccess() callback is called indicates that there were no client side errors, but the AuthenticationResult may still contain errors that the server returned.

Comment: Thanks. So the errors from AAD/ADFS have no classifications. All you get is free form string, correct?

Comment: Right, errors don't have classification for AAD or ADFS.